# Look around bash command history match

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I got a match for Ctrl+R In bash. How do I go back and forth around that position?
I have several commands that are run in sequence but I forget some of the commands names.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've found a match, you can use the up and down arrows to go to previous or next commands.

Comment: But only those that also match, no?

Comment: No, as soon as you press up or down, it exits the search mode, so it's just scrolling through your history. If you want to scroll back within matches, you press Ctrl-R, enter your search pattern, then Ctrl-R again and it'll find the next most recent command that matches the same pattern.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you! This comes to my mind when I was on windows machine.